# Converting Query from forEach in a better solution

Tags: php, pdo

```
foreach ($getComments as $comments) {
    $comAuthor=$comments['uid'];

    $getUser = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = $comAuthor")->fetch();
    $user = $getUser['name'];
    $comContent=$comments['cdata'];
    $comLikes=$comments['likes'];
    
    echo "<div class='comment'><a href='profile?uid=$comAuthor'>$user</a><p>$comContent</p><likes>$comLikes</likes></div>";
}
```

I have been trying to get this query to work in a forEach cycle, but after I have done my research I found out it's impossible to run it more than once. I need help trying to get this to work. I am new to PHP and a lot of stuff is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: are you getting an error? Is so, what is it?

Comment: No errors, thats the thing. I need to have query in a forEach, as I discussed in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` in the base query.

```
SELECT users.name, comments.cdata, comments.likes
FROM comments
INNER JOIN user ON comments.uid = user.uid
```

So in the `foreach` you already have the user name in the `$comments` variable.

Comment: So, I just put it in the initial query where I get all of the $comments items?

Comment: Wait, I need to get more than one comment. This doesn't work with more than one

Comment: In your code you trying to get the user from the comments results, so its should work because every comment has one user posted it. @mikeziroer

Comment: i just tested it here is the page https://frog-e.com/posts?id=1

Comment: I have 2 comments and only one shows, and I did everything correctly by replacing the query

Comment: can you help me/